# Reduce TCP send buffer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tcp, buffer

I have a windows 2008 R2 server, an app is constantly polling another server (using a Flash Socket) while waiting for a certain event to occur on that server. We are talking about milliseconds. When the receiving server is lagging, it's TCP receive window gets filled with polling requests and my server stops sending anything, but it keeps generating requests. They are stored in some network send buffer, I suppose. When I get an ACK from the receiving server, all polling requests that are waiting get send at once in a huge packet which overloads the receiver and everything repeats over again. I want to spread the requests evenly over time.

I have almost no influence over the software that generates requests. How can I reduce the send buffer, to make sure that no big chunks of data is sent to the other server when it's lagging? I'm fine with any hacks or global settings.
In my NIC's configuration window I can change "Transmit Buffers" setting, will it do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

That won't really work - the data isn't getting piled up on the sender, it's piling up on the recipient, having been received by the TCP socket and waiting for the application to pick it up, so lowering the send window won't help. (Fiddling with that buffer might shift the pileup, but those tunings are system-wide, and you'd need to manually cut the window in 4 places - not a pleasant approach.)

You don't have control over the sending application, how about the receiving application? Could have it discard all polling requests if a polling request has already been received in the past X seconds?

Comment: The data gets piled up on the sender, I can see this with MS's Netmon. In my specific situation I don't care about data getting piled up on the receiver too, my goal is to spread my requests evenly over time. I don't have any control over the receiving application. System-wide tuning is ok.